# Large relative error

Tags: calculus

When evaluating $f(x)=\left(\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\right)$, we observe large relative error as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Find a method to evaluate $f(x)$ to full machine precision for all $|x|<1$.

Comment: Yes I know the Taylor series for e^x. I thought about this problem for almost half an hour and i got nothing. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Note that the two terms in the numerator are the first two terms of the Taylor series. The subtraction loses accuracy when $x$ is small.  You should do that subtraction analytically, using the rest of the Taylor series in the numerator as far as needed.  Since $x$ is small, the series will converge quickly.

Comment: How to evaluate each term since we don't know the value of x?

Comment: Usually an algorithm will have a switch that evaluates this as written for large $x$ and switches to the Taylor series when $x$ is small.  For your problem, $x$ is guaranteed to be fairly small.  The factorial in the denominator grows so rapidly that the first neglected term is a good estimate of the truncation error.  When that gets smaller than machine epsilon times your computed quantity, you can stop.  For $x=1$ you need $\frac 1{n!} \lt (e-2)\epsilon$.  For smaller $x$, the $x^n$ term helps and you might be able to stop earlier.

Comment: Why is it (e-2)ϵ?

Comment: And is it true that for this question, we only need to say that when x=1, we stop at the n-th term (We'll find the n by using that equation above). For smaller xx, the xnxn term helps and you might be able to stop earlier?

Comment: It is $e-2$ because that is $\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ evaluated at $x=1$.  Have you found the Taylor series we are talking about? There is $x^n$ in the numerator of each term.  If $x=0.1$, that makes the terms decrease faster than when $x=1$, so you don't need so many to reach a given accuracy.

Comment: Oh i get it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Calculate the quantities $$\left\{ \frac{1}{2!}, \frac{x}{3!} , \frac{x^2}{4!} \cdots \right\}$$ by starting with $\frac12$ and repeatedly multiplying by $x$ and dividing by the next integer.  Terminate this when the last value is less than $0.18$ times the machine precision.  ($0.18$ because that is less than the machine $\frac12$ times the machine times the smallest possible actual result).
- Add these quantities *in reverse order* (to avoid losing precision in the smaller terms).

Comment: Obviously you have to omit the last step (multiplication with $x^2$), because the Maclaurin series starts 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}x+\frac{1}{4!}x^2+\frac{1}{5!}x^3+O(x^4).$$
And I suggest the minor correction, that you stop the computation when the last value is less than $\frac{1}{4}$ of the machine precision, because the leading term is $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $1$ (because $f(-1)\approx 0.37$ a threshold of $0.18\epsilon$  would  even be better).

Comment: Modified according to your (correct) observations @gammatester

Comment: I have another question: Since we don't know the value of x, how can we decide when to determinate it? Did you just substitute x with 1 or -1?

Comment: Why is 0.37 a threshold of 0.18ϵ? Isn't the full machine precision = 2^(-52)? And why does the first term matter? What's the difference when it is 1/2 or 1?

Comment: @J.doe: Basically because $|f(-1)|<1$. You know $1+\epsilon/2 = 1$ but $1/2+\epsilon/2 \ne 1/2,\;$ (but there is more: negative $x$ etc). My value is just $\approx |f(-1)|\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum value of $N$ such that

$$\frac1{(N+3)!} < \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon$ is machine precision (typically about $10^{-16}$ at double precision).  The reason this works is that the remainder term in the Taylor expansion about $x=0$ is about

$$\frac{x^{N+1}}{(N+3)!} $$

and the OP is interested in all $|x| \lt 1$.